# How to use setState() inside compoentWillMount ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

I'm new to ReactJs. I'm trying to create a firebase app using it. So in componentWillMount I'm checking if the user is logined or not and setting the state boolean value according to that

```
  componentWillMount() {
    var config = {...};
    Firebase.initializeApp(config)

    Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if(user){
        console.log("User logined");
        this.setState({
          isLogined : true
        })
      }else{
        console.log("User isn't logined");
        this.setState({
          isLogined : false
        })
      }
    })

  }
```

But it's showing setState() is not a function.

```
index.js:2178 TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at Object.next (App.js:31)
    at index.cjs.js:1353
    at index.cjs.js:1457
```

Need Help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

1) You'll want to move this code to `componentDidMount`.
`componentWillMount` is [deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671). [Here's](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/) some more info as to why you should prefer componentDidMount

2) Change your `onAuthStateChanged` callback to be an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
componentDidMount() {
var config = {...};
Firebase.initializeApp(config)

Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(user){
    console.log("User logined");
    this.setState({
      isLogined : true
    })
  }else{
    console.log("User isn't logined");
    this.setState({
      isLogined : false
    })
  }
})

}
```

Comment: I just copy pasted that from Firebase docs. I'll keep that in mind. Tysm

Comment: @Kim can you link the documentation? We should try to get it updated

Comment: Nope.. it's firebase's documentation for javascript projects. It was my fault :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from:

```
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
```

`this` is not refferring to the react component. Instead, try:

```
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
```